# How to set a cover using NReco pdf generator?

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf, nreco

Hi i'm using NReco pdf generator in my client's web app and i can't find a tutorial or instruction to ho set a cover for generated pdf.
Or if is ti possible to not show page number in first page.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather trivial, you need to use [HtmlToPdfConverter.GeneratePdf](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/?topic=html/M_NReco_PdfGenerator_HtmlToPdfConverter_GeneratePdf_1.htm) overload that accepts "cover" parameter:

```
string docHtml;
string coverHtml;
var pdfGen = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
var pdfBytes = pdfGen.GeneratePdf(documentHtml, coverHtml);
```

(GeneratePdfFromFile / GeneratePdfFromFiles methods have a parameter for cover page too)